# How to protect / conceal HVAC lines in yard

Tags: hvac, landscaping

Our air conditioner was previously surrounded by two large trees which made it hard to get near it. Now that the trees are gone, the lines are exposed and I don't want someone tripping over them or breaking them. Is there a straightforward way to protect these lines without redoing them entirely?

[image]

Comment: A small fence or a box over the pipe.  A taller fence if you want the people protected also from tripping.

Comment: it would make sense to clear all the debris before taking a picture

Comment: Or plant some shrubs.  Or leave the tiki torches stuck in the ground!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack up some landscaping blocks (or whatever blocks/bricks/stones) to make a wall taller than where the lines sit - or two walls, one on either side of the lines, as you prefer. One should serve to prevent tripping over them, two will give them more damage protection.

If the size suits, a planter, such as a windowbox might also work, and be easier to remove when servicing is required.